# Electron Compiled EXE Not working as expected

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-packager

I've been trying to "package" my Electron Application, using the below script, however when the `.exe` is created and I try to run said `.exe` I end up with an error listed below.

I feel very stupid asking this; but what is the issue causing this as this is the first time experiencing Electron, ive read through countless documents, stackoverflow questions in relation to my issue with no avail.

###### Script

```js
electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=images/icon/logo.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"TestApp\" && node installers/windows/createinstaller.js
```

###### Error

[image]

###### Package.json (as requested by comments)

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "electron test",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "installer:mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "installer:win": "electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=images/icon/test.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"test\" && node installers/windows/createinstaller.js",
    "installer:linux": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/png/icon.png --prune=true --out=release-builds"
  },
  
  "authors": [
    "Johnty"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord-rich-presence": "0.0.8",
    "discord.js": "^12.3.1",
    "electron-log": "^4.2.4",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "node-notifier": "^8.0.0",
    "update-electron-app": "^2.0.1",
    "web-remote-control": "^1.9.8",
    "webhook-discord": "^3.7.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "electron": "^10.4.7",
    "electron-packager": "^15.1.0",
    "electron-winstaller": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: It appears your Electron app is using the [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) package. This module should be imported at the top of your main.js file or file that it is referenced / used in. Ensure you have somthing simliar to `const axios = require('axios');` at the top of your file. Just to be sure, have you installed Axios from the command line? IE: `npm install axios`. If so, it should be listed in your package.json file. Some more information regarding this is needed to debug your issue.

Comment: Contents of the `package.json` would be helpful indeed.

Comment: @snwflk 
I've added the package.json :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`electron-packager`'s  [`prune`](https://electron.github.io/electron-packager/main/interfaces/electronpackager.options.html#prune) option removes any packages from the final bundle that are listed in the `devDependencies` section.

Since `axios` is listed there, it is removed from the bundle.

You should put it into the `dependencies` section and rebuild the bundle.